# VBS or Wildcard to copy file through unknown directory

Tags: vbscript, wildcard

```
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject") 
Set objFile = objFSO.GetFile("c:\temp\abc\123.xml") 
objFile.Copy "c:\programdata\ABC\DEF\XXXXXX\JKL\"
```

I need to move 123.xml to the \JKL directory but XXXXXX could be any directory name (unknown to me) on the 100 target PCs this script will be run - how can I wildcard this directory name or get around this problem?

Comment: Will there always be one and only one folder in `c:\programdata\ABC\DEF`? Or, if there are many, how do you chose which to use?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this function to determine the path of your `"JKL"` subfolder. Pass in the starting/root folder and the name of the subfolder that's two levels deep from that folder.

Note that this will return the *first* sub-subfolder it finds that matches `strName`. So, if you have more than one sub-subfolder named `"JKL"`, this may not be what you want.

```
Function GetSubSubFolder(strRoot, strName)

    Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

    For Each objFolder In objFSO.GetFolder(strRoot).SubFolders
        For Each objSubFolder In objFolder.SubFolders
            If StrComp(objSubFolder.Name, strName, vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
                GetSubSubFolder = objSubFolder.Path
                Exit Function
            End If
        Next
    Next

End Function
```

For your instance, the function call would look like this:

```
strFolder = GetSubSubFolder("c:\programdata\ABC\DEF", "JKL")
```

If the function returns an empty string, it means the sub-subfolder could not be found.